# Would a spinning, evenly charged sphere generate a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I could see how it would go either way.

On the one hand, there IS moving charge; on the other hand, it is not discernibly moving.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you call "discernibly" moving, is called a non-stationary current-density. Consider a wire with constant charge-flow at every cross section. Then this current is in the same sense not "discernibly" moving as your charge on the sphere. Still there is a magnetic field around the wire.

You can think of the charged sphere as infinitely many circular wires around the axis of rotation. All these wires create magnetic fields that add up. So yes, there is a magnetic field due to a rotating sphere.

For a calculation approach I suggest this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/173022/75518

Comment: So a 'spinning' electron would NOT produce a magnetic field, because (as a singular point source) it does not represent a flowing current.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Jiminion: There is no notion like "spinning point". Still, electrons have a property called *Spin*, which is kinda similar to angular momentum (this is what u mean by spinning), but still not the same! electrons have a [magnetic moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_magnetic_moment) due to this *Spin*, but it is usually not explained on a classical basis. If you get into the [dirac-equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation), you'll see that this magnetic moment is actually not caused by any "spinning" at all. Still, sometimes this visualisation is usefull.

Comment: Did the OP mean theoretically alone in space or somewhere here on Earth? I was under the assumption that the earth generates its own magnetic field; by its outer core moving relative to its solid, inner core. Doesn't this sphere have to spin relative to *something*? (and if it is, *then* the answer is, yes?) Or if it's charged it would have a MF, even without spinning?

Comment: @Mazura: You are right, motion is always relative to something. Here, the sphere is thought to be spinning relative to the (inertial) system of an observer, where the sphere's center of mass is not in motion. Furthermore, notions like electric- or magnetic-fields are relative to an observer, too. Think of a charge, that is at rest relative to one observer. This means there is *only* an electro-static-field. Now consider a second observer that is in uniform movement relative to the first one. He will see the charge in uniform movement and thus observe a magnetic- and electric-field!

Comment: The link is broken https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/173022/75518

Answer (score 1):

The things that induce a magnetic field are a current or a changing electric field (with respect to time). In this situation you have charges moving,so you have a J.dS, which means you have a current.

EDIT:

If you prefer a different approach, then consider the sphere to be an infinite amount of circular circuits (each with different radius because of the spherical surface).

So you know that when you have moving charges in a circuit, it means that you have current, and thus you have induced magnetic field.

So now you have infinite circular circuits one next to another. (Think of a solenoid with infinite turns. The same approach with different geometry can be made here-only for intuition though.)

Answer (score -6):

You have a moving charge and a circular moving that is an acceleration for what you need a force. Remember the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) $ \vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B $. This [vector cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) can be rewritten to $$ \vec B = \dfrac{\vec F \times \vec{qv}}{\|\vec{qv}\|^2}$$.

Edit: The equation was edited following https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219103/how-to-rewrite-a-vector-cross-product/1219127#1219127

Comment: I'm sure this identity is wrong! take vectors $a=(1,1,1), b=(2,0,0), c=(0,2,-2)$ then $a\times b = c$ but $c\times a \ne b$ and $c \times b \ne a$. Furthermore: $c\times a$ and $c\times b$ are not even (anit-)parallel to $b$ and $a$

Comment: (Since this has been flagged) Although MarcelKöpke is completely correct that this identity is wrong, this answer is an attempt to answer the question. Please do not flag *wrong* answers as "not an answer" or "low quality", but downvote them.

Comment: @MarcelKöpke: Please do your calculations with orthogonal vectors again.

Comment: but $B$ and $v$ are not orthogonal in general. $B$ is the magnetic field, e.g. induced by a current, and $v$ is the velocity of a charged particle flying in an **arbitrary** direction (e.g. this particle is not "part" of the current)

Comment: @MarcelKöpke: Make a sketch of the device from the above question. Is this the special case of orthogonal vectors?

Comment: The point is, that Lorentz-foce is the force applied to an particle that "interacts" with the above device by means of its magnetic field. One would usually not apply it to the device particles itself (since they are kept one a certain rotation anyway).

Comment: @MarcelKöpke Why not to apply the alignment of the electrons spin with the rotation of a cylinder and by this way the magnetic dipol moments will be aligned too. And this is the magnetic field you describe in your answer. Please proof both ways of calculation.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler your formula would give the needed $\vec{B}$ field to support the charges moving in circles, as if the charged sphere itself had no structural integrity. Which is not relevant to the question that was asked. (That's why people are saying you're wrong -- "F" is irrelevant to the question asked so there's no reason why "$F\cdot qv$" should mean anything, let alone be zero).

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy: Oh, so the sphere does not mean a rigid body? But if I follow the answer from Marcel Köpke there is a link to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173019/finding-magnetic-field-inside-rotating-sphere. This question is about a rigid body.  . .  I was happy about your comment but now in trouble again because of the link.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler it DOES mean rigid body, but all the FORCES involved are supplied by the structural integrity of the field. Your equation has nothing to do with the field actually generated by the charges. The Lorentz force law does not give you the field generated by the charges.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy: If an electron is revolving around an axis the electron feels a centrifugal force, it's accelerated. Since it is accelerated and it is moving one has the situation of a induced magnetic field. I try to see the special case of Lorentz force always in context with electromagnetic induction and its three phenomenons EM drive, EM generator and EM coil. According to the equation B=... a magnetic field parallel to the rotation axis has to be generated. This correspondes with Marcels answer.

Comment: @MarcelKöpke: If an electron is revolving around an axis the electron feels a centrifugal force, it's accelerated. Since it is accelerated and it is moving one has the situation of a induced magnetic field. I try to see the special case of Lorentz force always in context with electromagnetic induction and its three phenomenons EM drive, EM generator and EM coil. According to the equation B=... a magnetic field parallel to the rotation axis has to be generated. This correspondents with your answer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: If an electron is revolving around an axis the electron feels a centrifugal force, it's accelerated. Since it is accelerated and it is moving one has the situation of a induced magnetic field. I try to see the special case of Lorentz force always in context with electromagnetic induction and its three phenomenons EM drive, EM generator and EM coil. According to the equation B=... a magnetic field parallel to the rotation axis has to be generated. This correspondents with Marcels answer.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler the magnetic field of a charged spinning spherical shell is exactly like a point dipole outside the surface: http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/rotatingshell.pdf and is not "along the z axis", and Marcel's answer does not state that. The equations you are using are confused and are used without meaning. The equation $\nabla \times B=\mu_0 J$ contains different physics than the Lorentz force law.

Comment: there a two different kinds of equations in electrodynamics:$$$$
1) [Maxwell equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), which (given a charge density and current density) tell you what the electric- and magnetic-field is. Also they tell you how E and B influence each other (e.g. EM-waves).$$$$
2) [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), which given (!!!) an electric- and magnetic-field tell you what forces act on a charge $q$ with velocity $v$. It is not suited to calculate the fields.